# How to test that a HQL query compiles?

Tags: hibernate, testing

I have a number of HQL queries (~2000) that are generated from configuration XML files.

Of course it would be great to have integration tests that would cover all of these cases, but unfortunately this is old code from before the era where my company thought tests are a good idea.

Writing full integration tests that cover all of these files is clearly out of scope right now. However it would already help a lot to find configuration files that cause erroneous queries such as`from SomeRandomUnmappedClass` or `select propertyThatDoesNotExist from SomeClass` to be generated. A quick "compile check" without setting parameters and without communicating with an actual database should do the trick. But how can this be done?

(BTW: I am stuck on ancient Hibernate 3.3.2)

Comment: Why not create a test database using [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), which is an in-memory database ideally suited for testing purposes.

Comment: Because the generated queries can have parameters and I don't have values for the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is darn simple: Since you have a setup for integration tests that starts the hibernate context with an HSQLDB anyway you can just execute:

```
session.createQuery(hql);
```

This returns a query object and usually you would then set parameters and then execute the query. However during the `createQuery`-call the desired checks are already performed. If there is something wrong an exception is thrown. Just cut away parameter setting and execution!

(Sometimes the solution is just too obvious ;-))